# Maven Project Import wizard is not showing sub project poms

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, multi-module

I checked out a project from SVN into my local folder. It has root pom and all project multi level subfolders have pom files. When I tried to import and specify root directory, the import wizard shows only root pom. Not showing all poms from the sub folders. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the root POM declare the child modules? e.g. `<modules><module>child.artifactId</module></modules>`

Comment: No. It doesn't. But I was told, if I run mvn install on root pom, it downloads all dependencies for child projects as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its very likely that the parent pom doesn't define the child projects within a modules tag in its pom.xml.

Comment: yes, it does not have module tag. But I was told run mvn install on root pom so that all dependencies for the sub folders / modules will be downloaded. Is that the case?

Comment: if you add the child projects within <modules><module>child A<module><modules> in the parent's pom.xml, they should then show up in the Import projects wizard. and also, when you run mvn install now, from root project, it should download dependencies from your child projects as well. hope that helps.

Comment: Only if I specify modules tag in the root pom? Or not ncessary?